# Does the mage armour skill effect work with magic robes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> Mage armour - "Protection spells (like Stoneflsh) are twice as strong if not wearing armour

Does this count if I wear magic robes, or do I have to be completely naked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Armor in this game means anything with an armor rating. (It should also say "heavy|light armor" in the left corner)

Robes, even enchanted, don't have an armor value, so should be fair game.

Comment: Phew, I don't have to run around like a naked mad man.

Comment: @theorise but are you really having fun when you're not?

Comment: I also noticed that shields, while having an armor rating, do not count for the purposes of the Mage Armor perk. So you can still have a shield out and still get the Protection spell multiplier. I don't know if this is intended or a bug, though.

Comment: @Piitaa that's consistent with past Elder Scrolls games, too.

Comment: That is awesome, I was wondering about that @Piitaa

Answer (score 4):

Mage robes do not say 'Light/Heavy Armour', so my assumption is that they do count.

Otherwise, it'd be a little stupid (Mage armour...is naked armour?)